# Create Kafka Producer to send each message from the list

Tags: java, list, apache-kafka

I have kafka and zookeeper running in the docker-machine

I need to send kafka messages to kafka by using springboot.

List of Messages:

```
[[{"id":"0x804f","timestamp":1551684977690}],

[{"id":"1234","timestamp":155168497800}],

[{"id":"39339e82-6bd6-4ab6-9672-21d0df4d34eb","timestamp":1551684977690}],

[{"id":"a3173ca5-4cc4-408b-a058-879a298d6081","timestamp":155168497800}]]
```

This is what I tried for sample :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

public class Producer {
private Properties properties = new Properties();
String topicName = "tslistsbc";

public Producer(){
    String bootstrapServer = "docker-machineIP:9092";
    String keySerializer = StringSerializer.class.getName();
    String valueSerializer = StringSerializer.class.getName();
    String producerId = "simpleProducer";
    int retries = 2;

    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, producerId);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);

    KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    String value = "sample list"
    ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, "1",value);
    kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord);
    kafkaProducer.close();
}
```

Docker Image:
These containers are running in the docker machine

```
 zookeeper:
    build: ../components/zookeeper
    image: xxxx:${ZOOKEEPER}
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    build: ../components/kafka
    image: xxx:${EMD_KAFKA}
    container_name: image-kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "tslist:1:1,topic:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: "15728640"
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Error Message

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions.apiVersionToText(NodeApiVersions.java:167)
```

Its not working, the message is not being sent.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I'm not getting any error

Comment: which docker image you are using?

Comment: What did you see in your app debug logs?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: image-kafka:9092
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:182)
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:629)
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:186)
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:184)
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:139)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null

Comment: @YagoAzedias please see the updated question.

Comment: Why are you using docker-machine and building your own containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to access one of the docker compose containers externally from the docker compose started services (for instance by running your service in your IDE), you need to add the docker container name to your system's **hosts** file.

In Linux/Mac the hosts file is at **/etc/hosts** and in Windows its at **c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts**. According to the error you are getting, your hosts file should have an entry like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 image-kafka
```

Regarding the exception

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type 
[org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions.apiVersionToText(NodeApiVersions.java:167)
```

it is due to a mismatch between the used Kafka Server version and Kafka Client version ([check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794651/kafka-error-slf4j-failed-tostring-invocation-on-an-object-of-type-org-apach/)).

Comment: how to do I get the kafka server version.. what's the command

Comment: The Kafka Server version should be apparent from the name of the image in your docker compose Kafka service. The Kafka Client library version will be whatever you have specified in your Gradle/Maven build file.

Comment: Please don't suggest using hosts files. The advertised listeners are a configurable property for a reason